# How to install Canon LBP3010 drivers on Fedora

Tags: linux, drivers, fedora, printer

Fedora version is: 29 64bit

I downloaded [Canon CAPT Printer Driver for Linux 64 bit](https://www.canon-europe.com/support/consumer_products/products/printers/laser/i-sensys_lbp3010.aspx?type=drivers&driverdetailid=tcm:13-823414&os=Linux%20(64-bit)&language=EN) then installed

```
sudo dnf upgrade -y
sudo dnf install cups-*
sudo dnf install cndrvcups-common-2.20-1.x86_64.rpm
sudo dnf install cndrvcups-capt-2.20-1.x86_64.rpm
```

I plugged the printer usb and power on. I selected `add printer` under `settings->devices->printers`, and the printer is recognized. If I click "print test page", the job is put in queue and nothing more happens.

What can I do to understand why?

Thank you

Comment: OK, stupid question at the level of "did you check that it was plugged in", but just to rule this out: did you verify that the printer is "online".  For various and sundry reasons (such as faults, like out of ink, paper jam, etc.), the printer takes itself offline.  Once the fault is fixed, you typically need to hit a button to make the printer active again.  This is a 3 month-old question, so this is unlikely, but...  Also, can you verify that this is still a problem for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following worked on Fedora 31 and Fedora 29 (both 64bit).

**Set ccpd daemon to start at startup**

*Add the following line to* `/etc/init.d/rc.local`

```
> /etc/init.d/ccpd start
```

*Exeute the following commands on the shell*

**Install required libraries**

```
> dnf install -y libgcc libstdc++ popt libxml2
```

**Install printer drivers**

```
> rpm -ivh cndrvcups-common-2.20-1.x86_64.rpm
> rpm -ivh cndrvcups-capt-2.20-1.x86_64.rpm
```

**Restart cups**

```
> systemctl restart cups
```

**Register printer with the printer spooler**

```
> /usr/sbin/lpadmin -p LBP3010 -m CNCUPSLBP3050CAPTK.ppd -v ccp://localhost:59687 –E
> /usr/sbin/ccpdadmin -p LBP3010 -o /dev/usb/lp0
```

**Start ccpd daemon**

```
> /etc/init.d/ccpd start
```

Plug the printer usb cable, and power on. Driver is successfully installed.